# разбор и получение данных из XML

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, xmlparser

Гружу ajax-ом XML. При разборе XML нужно получить данные если есть совпадение по селектору. Далее нужно эти данные сложить и вывести общую сумму.

Вот код:

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: link,          
dataType: "xml",
success: xmlParser});

 function xmlParser(xml) {
   var summ                     
   $(xml).find("stat>advcampaign:contains(15454)").each(function () {                   
      payment = +$(this).siblings("payment").text();
      summ=   //дальше не знаю как сделать

                });
```

вот файл XML

```
<stats>
<stat>
<status_updated>2016-10-20</status_updated>
<advcampaign>15454</advcampaign>
<payment>1.40</payment>
</stat>
<stat>
<status_updated>2016-10-19</status_updated>
<advcampaign>15454</advcampaign>
<payment>2.10</payment>
</stat>
<stat>
<status_updated>2016-10-19</status_updated>
<advcampaign>15453</advcampaign>
<payment>1.04</payment>
</stat>
<stat>
<status_updated>2016-10-18</status_updated>
<advcampaign>15454</advcampaign>
<payment>1.33</payment>
</stat>
</stats>
```

как сложить полученные числа?
XML только для примера он может быть довольно большим

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function xmlParser(xml) {
    var summ = 0;            
    $(xml).find("stat>advcampaign:contains(15454)").each(function () {                   
          payment = +$(this).siblings("payment").text();
          summ += payment;
     }
);
```

Comment: спасибо добрый человек))) я голову сломал почему мне NaN выдаёт, оказывается нужно переменной summ значение 0 прописать)))